# 404 error code when attempting to access an API endpoint but works normally on others

Tags: spring-boot, http, http-status-code-404, endpoint

I have an endpoint in the `com.project.users` package that will fetch the information of the logged in user:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("me")
    public User me() {
        Optional<User> ouser = repository.findById(1);
        return ouser.get();
    }
}
```

I have another controller within `com.project.beneficiary` and I am trying to access a method through a POST request but instead, I receive a 404 error message:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/api/beneficiaries
Request method:POST
Remote address:127.0.0.1:8080
Status code:
404
Version:HTTP/1.1
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

{"timestamp":"2019-04-16T01:46:37.395+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/api/beneficiaries"}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/beneficiaries")
public class BeneficiaryController {
    @Autowired
    private BeneficiaryRepository repository;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public Beneficiary addBeneficiary(@Valid @RequestBody Beneficiary beneficiary) {
        return repository.save(beneficiary);
    }
}
```

I've dealt with CORS, and I think it worked because I see no message about it anywhere. All these packages are on the same level as the application's starting point, but it is weird why one is seen and the other is not. Something to do with the POST request?

I found something about setting up the context within `application.properties`, but whatever I put there will cause the 404 error even from Insomnia software. I tried adding the `/beneficiaries`, `/api/beneficiares`, and just `/api`, but I don't think it is anything to do with it. No error messages in the console are visible.

Comment: Try remove `("/")` from your `@PostMapping`?

Comment: Doest GET /api/me work? If it works, try to modify `/api/beneficiaries` with `/api2/beneficiaries` and test the POST with the new path.

Comment: @Mr.J4mes, write an answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo :). I ran into a similar problem some time back. Took me hours to resolve. Just remove `("/")` from your @PostMapping.